# Sending JSON from iOS, weird response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to send JSON from my iOS.
This is what I have so far:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)SendJSON:(NSString *)jsonString toAddress:(NSString *)address
{    
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply options:kNilOptions error:nil] );
    NSDictionary *jsonresponse = POSTReply ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:POSTReply options:kNilOptions error:nil] : nil;

    return jsonresponse;
}
```

It works fine if I send the jsonString like this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", self.txtUsername.text, self.txtPassword.text];
```

But If I try to send using the JSON format:

```
@"{ \"username\" : \"%@\", \"password\" : \"%@\" }"
```

it does not work
any ideas why?

PS: This information is being sent to a Rails server.

Comment: The first one isn't a JSON string -- it appears intended to be a URL encoding.  The second should produce valid JSON (though it's always hard to tell with the escapes), but of course only if processed through `stringWithFormat`.  The two would not be interchangeable -- they'd have to be transmitted differently.

Comment: Note that you should not send passwords "in the clear", but should use the encrypted password facilities of https or some other protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to set the Content-Type appropriately since you're sending JSON in the POST body.

This ought to do the trick, replace your x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: NO WAY! Thank you, that solved the problem.... I will accept it once I am allowed to.